# How to apply this hint in my sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
/*+ INDEX (TARGET_TABLE W_GL_ACCOUNT_D_U1) INDEX (SCD_OUTER W_GL_ACCOUNT_D_U1)*/
```

Need your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX (TARGET_TABLE W_GL_ACCOUNT_D_U1) INDEX (SCD_OUTER W_GL_ACCOUNT_D_U1)*/  * 
FROM TARGET_TABLE, SCD_OUTER;
```

See [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm)

Comment: Not necessarily SELECT, you can also update/insert ETC on the same way

Comment: @sagi yes, of course. The question is " How to apply this hint in my **sql query**" and I thought that the author had in mind SELECT

Comment: Yea I was just pointing it out in case the OP doesn't know that(which is very possible) , thats why i said 'you' :)

Comment: Thank you. i need to update this in sql query /*+ INDEX (TARGET_TABLE W_GL_ACCOUNT_D_U1) INDEX (SCD_OUTER W_GL_ACCOUNT_D_U1)*/

Comment: @Dileep I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.

Comment: Actually iam new to informatica. i have few oracle delivered mappings. for better tuning perpose we need to add hints to that source query. I never used hints in any queries yet. so i just want to know how to use hints.

Comment: @Dileep Then as I wrote See [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm)